# Controlling the formatting of seq fields inside word equations

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes, cross-reference

So I have several appendices that look something like this:
**Appendix A: Equations**
**Appendix B: Sample Calculations**
etc.

The letter is controlled as such:

```
Appendix [{seq AppL \*ALPHABETIC}]: Example
```

Where the brackets represent the bookmark that references that value.  This means I can put more appendices before, after, whatever, and the lettering will update.

Each appendix also contains various equations, that reference the letter of the appendix, and the equation number, like this:

```
y = mx + b #({REF AppEq \*MERGEFORMAT}.{seq AppEq})
```

The problem is that whenever I update everything (ctrl+A, f9), the letters in the equation numbering revert to bold.  The *MERGEFORMAT switch should prevent this, but it doesn't seem to work inside of equations (it works in my headers, and I tested it to work in the body).

Is there any way to fix this, some alternate way of approaching it, or at least some way of reducing the annoyance this causes?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a solution to the issue - I believe this to be a bug with Word.  However, I have found a workable workaround by using a macro to update the fields rather than doing so manually.  This macro will show the field codes, unbold any that begin with "^d seq AppL", update all the fields in the document, then rebold the correct fields and hide field codes.  I can't claim that it's robust or efficient - but maybe it will help someone down the line:

```
Sub UpdateRefs()
'Setup / checks
If Documents.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Show field codes
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True

'Unbold Appendix labels so they don't propagate.
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^d seq AppL"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWholeWord = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

'Update all fields in document.
Dim oStory As Object
Dim oToc As Object
For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    oStory.Fields.Update
Next oStory
For Each oToc In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
    oToc.Update
Next oToc

'Rebold for looks.
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^d seq AppL"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWholeWord = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

'Hide field codes.
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a SEQ field which you then manually bookmark, you could just create outline numbered styles for your main Appendix numbering.

You can then use either:

- a LISTNUM field (which will automatically sequentially number within the appendix);
- a combination of STYLEREF field (for appendix number - automatically picked up based on which appendix you are in) and the existing SEQ field (for equation number); or
- a cross-reference (for appendix number) and the existing SEQ field (for equation number).

Note if you use the STYLEREF or cross-reference fields, you'll want to add the "\t" switch so that it shows just the appendix letter (ie "A" and not "Appendix A" - as when setting up your outline numbering you will have typed Appendix in the "Enter formatting for number" textbox before adding the field).

I'd use a LISTNUM field (rather than the combinations of fields).  For this option, the appendix letter will have been set up to automatically appear by using the "Include level number from" Level 1 option.

[image]